# How do you change a "a href" link but only certain selected ones in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, click, live, hyperlink

I want to change the behaviour on a "a href" link but only on ones that have a custom made attribute called open

e.g.

```
<a href="#" action="open">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk/"></a>
```

I want to change only the behaviour of the first one. So I do a:

```
jQuery('a[action|=open]').live('click', function(evt) {
      do something;
});
```

but nothing happens. The selector selects all the specified elements but the click event is not exectued. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: p.s. I tried it and it works if I add a class to it but can it work with a custom attribute?

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to do this with a class name:

```
$('a.open').click(function(){...})

<a href="#" class="open">Link 1</a>
```

Comment: +1, more compatible cross-browser, and keeps the markup valid against the spec

Comment: I agree, although I think ip's code should work, it does in my tests.

Comment: Strange, because it doesn't work if I am not using a class. What browser did u tested on Adam?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work, but not all browsers support custom attributes.  I suggest following @Diodeus' answer, and using classes.  This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Xvrk/) works for me in Chrome, but it may not in all browsers.